# hashing image with watermark in laravel

Tags: laravel, hash, intervention

i use in my project image package Intervention-Image
to add watermark to every uploaded image in serve  i use code blow but have error in hashing 
hashing give me the hash of watermark.png only every time

```
Route::post('/upload_image',function (Request $request)
{

    $real_path = Image::make($request->file('image')->getRealPath());

    $img_for_hash = Image::make($real_path);

    $img = Image::make($real_path);

    //  calculate md5 hash of encoded image
     $hash = md5($img_for_hash->__toString());

     // use hash as a name
    $path = "images/{$hash }.jpg";



    $watermark =  Image::make(public_path('watermark.png'));



    $img->insert($watermark, 'bottom-right', 10, 10);



    // save it locally to ~/public/images/{$hash}.jpg
    $img->save(public_path($path));

    return $hash ;

})->name('upload_image');
```

view

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Upload Image</title>
</head>
<body>

      <form action="{{ route('upload_image') }}" method="post"  enctype="multipart/form-data" >

      @csrf

      <input type="file" name="image">

     <button type="submit"> upload </button>

      </form>

</body>
</html>
```

are any solution use call back or this because watermark ?? i don't know why this code give me same hash every time .

Comment: What does `$img_for_hash->__toString()` output on a var_dump()? Not sure what kind of string you'd get from an Image object (maybe blank), but I assume it's the same no matter what the Image data actually is.

Comment: ```` $img_for_hash->__toString() ```` return blank but before i add water mark to image  hashing work correct why now work when i use watermark

Comment: I don't know what you had before you added the watermark but your `$hash` is always going to be the same if the `$img_for_hash->__toString()` is always blank.

Comment: `$real_path = Image::make($request->file('image')->getRealPath());` `        $tmp_path  ="{$real_path->dirname}\\{$real_path->basename}" ;
` `        $hash = md5_file($tmp_path);
`     i use this code and worked perfect thank you for your time